# Count nodes with xpath and count

Tags: php, xpath, count

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$xmlString = '
        <SHOP xmlns="http://www.example.com/ns/offer/1.0">
            <SHOPITEM>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <PRODUCT>T-shirt</PRODUCT>
                <PRICE>19,22</PRICE>
            </SHOPITEM>
            <SHOPITEM>
                <ID>2</ID>
                <PRODUCT>Trousers</PRODUCT>
                <PRICE>87,54</PRICE>
            </SHOPITEM>
        </SHOP>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
$x_s_products = $xml->xpath("/SHOP/SHOPITEM");
$cnt_x_products = count($x_s_products);
echo $cnt_x_products;
?>
```

The problem is that the `$cnt_x_products` is 0. But it is not true. If I delete *xmlns attribute*, everything is OK. But I must have this attribute there. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php ?

Comment: @MarcB How does it solve my problem? It doesn't return me the right number of SHOPITEM nodes.

Comment: because if removing the namespace attribute makes things work, then obviously it's the name space causing problems, and registering it will fix the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a namespcae, you must [**register**](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php) that namespace :

```php
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('n', 'http://www.example.com/ns/offer/1.0');
```

now this works :

```php
$x_s_products = $xml->xpath("//n:SHOPITEM");
$cnt_x_products = count($x_s_products);
echo $cnt_x_products;
```

outputs 2.